# Вывод строк в Go

Tags: golang

```go
    fmt.Print("на столе: ")
    for _, item := range location.Items {
        fmt.Printf("%s, ", item)
    }
```

То, что я получаю: `на столе: ключи, конспекты,`. То, что я должен получить: `на столе: ключи, конспекты.` (в конце точка). Можно ли как-то определить при выводе разделителем запятую, а окончанием - точку? Не обязательно Printf, не обязательно из fmt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понятно какого у вас типа поле location.Items.

Если []string то можно сделать так

```
fmt.Printf("%s.", strings.Join(location.Items, ", "))
```

Если другого типа то как вариант собрать все в один slice, а потом так же сждойнить в строку функцией **strings.Join**

И третий вариант, который приходит в голову, подсчитать сколько элементов в слайсе и на последнем элементе ставить точку в конце

```
count := len(location.Items)
i := 0;
sep := ", "
for _, item := range location.Items {
    i++
    if i == count {
        sep = "."
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s%s", item, sep)
}
```